# The underlay of C# where() method and C# HashTable

Tags: c#, data-structures, hashtable, where-clause

I am new in C#, having got used to Java and its data structures. Recently, when I wrote C#, trying to get the list of results based on users' choices. I used HashTable in C# but people say I can call where() method in List.

I am wondering the underlay of where method (array? or some other data structure?)so that I can figure out the real cost of where() function and HashTable.

Also, I know most of HashTable is created based on array or BST, so how does HashTable work in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I wouldn't use [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) in C#, but instead use [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), as this provides type safety.

Both classes have access that approaches O(1) for accessing items in the collection.  This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx):

> Getting or setting the value of this property approaches an O(1) operation.

Note that using a `List<T>` will effectively use an array internally, which means [`.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) becomes an O(n) *filter*.  For finding a single element, `FirstOrDefault` is typically a better choice.  If there aren't many items in the collection, this is often fine, but if you need fast access, then a `Dictionary<T,U>` is a better option.